# How to solve the equation to plot the deformation curve of the actuator?

Tags: numerical-methods, classical-mechanics, continuum-theory

Thanks for reading this.
I ask the question from the following research article ([https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2019/sm/c9sm01672d#:~:text=When%20the%20magnetic%20field%20strength,increase%20of%20magnetic%20field%20strength.](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2019/sm/c9sm01672d#:%7E:text=When%20the%20magnetic%20field%20strength,increase%20of%20magnetic%20field%20strength.))

The following equations are used plot the deformation curve of the actuator. I don't know how did they solve the equations.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

It was mentioned in the article that the above equations belonged to a typical boundary value problem of nonlinear ordinary differential equations. And an analytical solution to the problem was not easy to achieve, and numerical calculation of the shooting method would usually be used to solve such a problem.

I would highly appreciate any hints to solve the equations and to plot the deformation curves.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I doubt anyone is going to read all that. It is not at all obvious which equations you are talking about. Unless you do more work to be very specific about your exact problem, no one is going to try and spend time guessing what your problem is.